# beautifulsoup next_siblings generator doesn't loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, generator

This a sample reproduction for the issue

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

data = soup("""
<div>
<h3 id="pivot"></h3>
<table></table>
<h3 id="next-head"></h3>
<table></table>
<h3 id="next2-head"></h3>
</div>
""", 'lxml')

exists = data.find('h3', {'id': 'pivot'})

print('exists', exists)
tables = soup('<div></div>', 'lxml')
div = tables.find('div')

for sib in (exists.next_siblings):
    print('sibling', sib)
    if sib.name == 'h3':
        print('break')
        break
    div.append(sib)

print('tables', tables)
```

The above code prints nothing

output:

```
exists <h3 id="pivot"></h3>
sibling

tables <html><body><div>
</div></body></html>
```

whereas another variant works as expected

```py
# same as above
...

print('exists', exists)
tables = soup('<div></div>', 'lxml')
div = tables.find('div')
tabs = []
for sib in (exists.next_siblings):
    print('sibling', sib)
    if sib.name == 'h3':
        print('break')
        break
    tabs.append(sib)

print('tabs', tabs)
```

The tabs variable contains the expected results and the generator expands

```
exists <h3 id="pivot"></h3>
sibling

sibling <table></table>
sibling

sibling <h3 id="next-head"></h3>
break
tabs ['\n', <table></table>, '\n']
```

Also making the generator as a list `list(existing.next_siblings)` in the first sample will fix this weird issue.

Is this a python bug or a beautiful soup bug or this is the intended behaviour?

```sh
λ pip freeze | grep 'beautifulsoup4'
beautifulsoup4==4.9.1

λ python -V
Python 3.8.0
```

Comment: It's not weird...In the first example, you're changing the document tree while iterating over it.  `div.append(sib)` will remove the `sib` from the tree (in this case the `sib` is of type empty `NavigableString`) and the loop ends. As you wrote, you need to first put the siblings to a list and then iterate over them.

Comment: I didn't know appending to a different tree would delete it from the existing one. I just looked at the source, was under the assumption that it would make a copy. Thank you. @AndrejKesely would you like to answer this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example:

```
for sib in (exists.next_siblings):
    print('sibling', sib)
    if sib.name == 'h3':
        print('break')
        break
    div.append(sib)
```

you're modifying the document tree (with `div.append(sib)`) while iterating over it. The command `div.append(sib)` removes `sib` from the document tree `exists` and places it inside the tree `tables`. This is *bad* practice, as it only does one iteration.

In this first iteration , the `sib` is of type `NavigableString` with value `"\n"` (newline). So when you will print `tables`, you can see a newline after the opening `<div>` tag.

The correct approach is to store the siblings to list and then iterate over this list.